# Android : How do i style a DatePicker and TimePicker?

Tags: android, styles, datepicker, timepicker

I need to develop an application where i need to style a date and time picker,

I am having trouble setting the colors of the text and the separators of the components.

How do i override or write a new style object so that i can alter the appearance of the date/time pickers?

Basically all i want to do is change the style of the components e.g.

- Change the text color
- Change the separator color
- Change the selection color
- Change the background color

Comment: Please make your question more understandable and brief.

Comment: It is already understandable and brief from my point of view